# How do i reduce the size of my background image without overlapping content on my webpage

Tags: html, css, background, size, background-image

Hi i'm fairly new to HTML/CSS/Javascript, im struggling to reduce the size of my background images within my slider carousel on my webpage. What i'm trying to do is reduce the size of my background image so it sits on top of my login rather than below and then have a black background behind my login.

Please look at my image of webpage >  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jyams.jpg

```css
    html body
    {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
    
    body{
        height:100%;
        background-color:black !important;
    }
    
    /*-------------header-----------*/
    
    
    header
    {
        height:110px;
        line-height: 110px;
        position:fixed;
        z-index:1;
        width:100%;
    }
    
    .secondary{
        background-color:darkorange;
        box-shadow:0px 0px 15px 0px;
        transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    }
    
    /*-------------nav-----------*/
    
    
    ul
    {
        list-style:none;
       
    }
    
    ul li
    {
        display:inline-block;
        
    }
    
    header nav
    {
        float: right;
    }
    
    .logo img
    {
        margin-top:-20px;
        height:30px;
    }
    
    header nav ul li a 
    {
        padding-right: 25px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: white;
        transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    }
    
    header nav ul li a:hover
    {
        text-decoration: none;
        color:black;
    }
    
    /*-------------slider-----------*/
    
    
    .img1
    {
        background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.6),rgba(0,0,0,0.7)),url(work.jpg);
        background-size:100% 100%;
        
        
    }
    
    .slider,.slider ul,.slider ul li
    {
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
        color:white;
        text-align: center;
        padding:0px;
        
    }
    
    .slider h2
    {
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-top:260px;
    }
    
    .slider span
    {
        color:orange;
    }
    
    .slider a 
    {
        padding: 10px 40px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        
    }
    
    /*-------------slider-button-----------*/
    
    
    .slider a.btn-half
    
    {
        background-color: orange;
        color: white;
        width:200px;
    }
    
    .slider a.btn-half:hover
    {
        opacity:0.7;
        transition:0.5s ease-in;
    }
    
    
    
    
    .img2
    {
        background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.6),rgba(0,0,0,0.7)),url(work2.jpg);
        background-size:100% 100%;
    }
    
    .img3
    {
        background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.6),rgba(0,0,0,0.7)),url(work3.jpg);
        background-size:100% 100%;
    }
    
    .slider i
    {
        font-size:30px;
        margin-right:10px;
    }
    
    /*-------------login-----------*/
    
    
    
    .login-box
    {
        width:280px;
        position:absolute;
        top:1000px;
        left:50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        color:white;
    }
    
    .login-box h1 
    {
        width:100px;
        font-size:40px;
        border-bottom: 6px solid darkorange;
        margin-bottom:50px;
        padding:13 px 0;
    }
    
    .textbox
    {
        width:100%;
        overflow:hidden;
        font-size:20px;
        padding:8px 0;
        margin:8px 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid darkorange;
    }
    
    .textbox i 
    {
        width:26px;
        float:left;
        text-align:center;
    }
    
    .textbox input
    {
        border:none;
        outline:none;
        background:none;
        color:white;
        font-size:17px;
        width:80%;
        float:left;
        margin:0 10px;
    }
    
    .btn
    {
        width:100%;
        background:none;
        border:2px solid darkorange;
        color:white;
        padding:5px;
        font-size:17px;
        cursor:pointer;
        margin:12px 0;
    }
    
    .btn:hover
    {
        opacity:0.7;
        transition:0.5s ease-in;
    }
    
    /*-------------FAQ-----------*/
    
    .fqcontainer
    {
        max-width: 60%;
        margin:0 auto;
        padding:70px 0 20px;
        width:100%;
    }
    
    
    .fqcontainer h1
    {
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'roboto', 'sans-serif';
        font-size: 60px;
        margin:50px 0 0;
        color: white;
    }
    
    .acc
    {
        border-bottom:1px solid white;
    }
    
    .acc h3
    {
        font-size:25px;
        background-color: black rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
        color: white;
        padding:15px;
        margin:0;
        cursor:pointer;
        font-family:'roboto','sans-serif';
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        position:relative;
    }
    
    .acc h3:after
    {
        content: '+';
        position:absolute;
        right: 20px;
        font-size:40px;
        top:50%;
        transform:translateY(-50%);
    }
    
    .acc.active h3:after
    {
        content:'-';
    }
    
    .fqcontent
    {
        background-color:white;
        margin-top:0;
        line-height:1.5;
        display:none;
    }
    
    
    .content-inner
    {
        padding:15px;
        
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    /*-------------footer-----------*/
    
    
    .footer {
       width:100%;
        background-color: darkorange;
        padding:50px 0px;
        
        
    }
    
    
    footer nav
    {
        text-align:center;
    }
    
    
    footer nav ul li a 
    {
        padding-right: 25px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: white;
        transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    }
    
    footer nav ul li a:hover
    {
        text-decoration: none;
        color:black;
    }
```

```html
   <html>
   <body>
        <!-------------Header/Nav----------->
        <header>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <a href="index.html" class="logo"><img src="logo.png"></a>
                    <nav>
                        <ul>
    
                            <li><a href="#login-box">Log In</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">FAQ</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">My Surveys</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    
        <!-------------Slider----------->
    
        <section class="slider">
            <ul class="slider-carousel" id="slider-carousel">
    
                <li class="img1">
                    <h2>Slider<span>Slider</span></h2>
                    <p>Hello World</p>
                    <i class="fab fa-apple"></i>
                    <i class="fab fa-android"></i>
                    <i class="fab fa-windows"></i>
                    <p><br>Curabitur sodales sem nec nisl finibus, nec suscipit magna euismod.Praesent nibh leo, auctor vel po rttitor in, auctor et sapien.<br> Nullam et nulla rutrum, convallis tellus vitae, eleifend massa
                    </p><br>
                    <a href="" class="btn btn-half">Get Started</a>
    
                </li>
    
    
                <li class="img2">
                    <h2>Slider<span>Slider</span></h2>
                    <p>Hello World</p>
                    <i class="fab fa-apple"></i>
                    <i class="fab fa-android"></i>
                    <i class="fab fa-windows"></i>
                    <p><br>Curabitur sodales sem nec nisl finibus, nec suscipit magna euismod.Praesent nibh leo, auctor vel po rttitor in, auctor et sapien.<br> Nullam et nulla rutrum, convallis tellus vitae, eleifend massa
                    </p><br>
                    <a href="" class="btn btn-half">Get Started</a>
    
                </li>
    
    
                <li class="img3">
                    <h2>Slider<span>Slider</span></h2>
                    <p>Hello World</p>
                    <i class="fab fa-apple"></i>
                    <i class="fab fa-android"></i>
                    <i class="fab fa-windows"></i>
                    <p><br>Curabitur sodales sem nec nisl finibus, nec suscipit magna euismod.Praesent nibh leo, auctor vel po rttitor in, auctor et sapien.<br> Nullam et nulla rutrum, convallis tellus vitae, eleifend massa
                    </p><br>
                    <a href="" class="btn btn-half">Get Started</a>
    
                </li>
    
            </ul>
    
        </section>
    
        <!-------------Login----------->
    
        <div class="login-box">
            <div id="login-box">
                <h1>Login</h1>
    
                <div class="textbox">
                    <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="" value="">
                </div>
    
    
                <div class="textbox">
                    <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Password" name="" value="">
                </div>
    
                <input class="btn" type="button" name="" value="Sign In">
    
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <!-------------FAQ----------->
    
    
        <div class="fqcontainer">
            <h1>FAQ Section</h1>
            <div class="acc">
                <h3>Question 1: What is?</h3>
                <div class="fqcontent">
                    <div class="content-inner">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In sapien turpis, tincidunt nec maximus et, elementum vel massa. Sed quis suscipit tortor, vel lacinia enim. Pellentesque posuere a urna eget fermentum. Vivamus tincidunt varius
                            turpis, eget suscipit arcu aliquam vel. Maecenas fermentum tellus vel euismod porttitor. Curabitur sodales sem nec nisl finibus, nec suscipit magna euismod. Praesent nibh leo, auctor vel porttitor in, auctor et sapien. Nullam et
                            nulla rutrum, convallis tellus vitae, eleifend massa</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="acc">
                <h3>Question 1: What is?</h3>
                <div class="fqcontent">
                    <div class="content-inner">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In sapien turpis, tincidunt nec maximus et, elementum vel massa. Sed quis suscipit tortor, vel lacinia enim. Pellentesque posuere a urna eget fermentum. Vivamus tincidunt varius
                            turpis, eget suscipit arcu aliquam vel. Maecenas fermentum tellus vel euismod porttitor. Curabitur sodales sem nec nisl finibus, nec suscipit magna euismod. Praesent nibh leo, auctor vel porttitor in, auctor et sapien. Nullam et
                            nulla rutrum, convallis tellus vitae, eleifend massa</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="acc">
                <h3>Question 1: What is?</h3>
                <div class="fqcontent">
                    <div class="content-inner">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In sapien turpis, tincidunt nec maximus et, elementum vel massa. Sed quis suscipit tortor, vel lacinia enim. Pellentesque posuere a urna eget fermentum. Vivamus tincidunt varius
                            turpis, eget suscipit arcu aliquam vel. Maecenas fermentum tellus vel euismod porttitor. Curabitur sodales sem nec nisl finibus, nec suscipit magna euismod. Praesent nibh leo, auctor vel porttitor in, auctor et sapien. Nullam et
                            nulla rutrum, convallis tellus vitae, eleifend massa</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    
        </div>
    
        <!-------------Footer----------->
    
        <footer>
            <div class="footer">
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Log In</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">FAQ</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">My Surveys</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </footer>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

thats what you need to change/add in your css:

```css
/*-------------login-----------*/
.login-box{
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}
#login-box {
  width: 280px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
}
```

your parent div of your login section (*.login-box*) needs a "position" value (eg: position: relative), then your Login Box gets position **inside** the *.login-box*.

with a background image you have to set a specific height for your parent div.

If you use an image-tag inside your .login-box div   then the div would be as heigh as the image itself

running example (full code):

```css
html body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black !important;
}


/*-------------header-----------*/

header {
  height: 110px;
  line-height: 110px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
}

.secondary {
  background-color: darkorange;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}


/*-------------nav-----------*/

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

header nav {
  float: right;
}

.logo img {
  margin-top: -20px;
  height: 30px;
}

header nav ul li a {
  padding-right: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}

header nav ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}


/*-------------slider-----------*/

.img1 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url(http://lorempixel.com/1920/1080/);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.slider,
.slider ul,
.slider ul li {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
}

.slider h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 260px;
}

.slider span {
  color: orange;
}

.slider a {
  padding: 10px 40px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}


/*-------------slider-button-----------*/

.slider a.btn-half {
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
  width: 200px;
}

.slider a.btn-half:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in;
}

.img2 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url(http://lorempixel.com/1920/1080/);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.img3 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url(http://lorempixel.com/1920/1080/);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.slider i {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}


/*-------------login-----------*/
.login-box{
position: relative;
height: 100vh;
}
#login-box {
  width: 280px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
}

.login-box h1 {
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 40px;
  border-bottom: 6px solid darkorange;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  padding: 13 px 0;
}

.textbox {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid darkorange;
}

.textbox i {
  width: 26px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

.textbox input {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 17px;
  width: 80%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.btn {
  width: 100%;
  background: none;
  border: 2px solid darkorange;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 17px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 12px 0;
}

.btn:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in;
}


/*-------------FAQ-----------*/

.fqcontainer {
  max-width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 70px 0 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

.fqcontainer h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'roboto', 'sans-serif';
  font-size: 60px;
  margin: 50px 0 0;
  color: white;
}

.acc {
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.acc h3 {
  font-size: 25px;
  background-color: black rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'roboto', 'sans-serif';
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  position: relative;
}

.acc h3:after {
  content: '+';
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  font-size: 40px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.acc.active h3:after {
  content: '-';
}

.fqcontent {
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: 0;
  line-height: 1.5;
  display: none;
}

.content-inner {
  padding: 15px;
}


/*-------------footer-----------*/

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: darkorange;
  padding: 50px 0px;
}

footer nav {
  text-align: center;
}

footer nav ul li a {
  padding-right: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}

footer nav ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}


/* CHANGES */

.slider {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <!-------------Header/Nav----------->


  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <a href="index.html" class="logo"><img src="logo.png"></a>
        <nav>
          <ul>

            <li><a href="#login-box">Log In</a></li>
            <li><a href="">FAQ</a></li>
            <li><a href="">My Surveys</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <!-------------Slider----------->

  <section class="slider">
    <ul class="slider-carousel" id="slider-carousel">

      <li class="img1">
        <h2>Slider<span>Slider</span></h2>
        <p>Hello World</p>
        <i class="fab fa-apple"></i>
        <i class="fab fa-android"></i>
        <i class="fab fa-windows"></i>
        <p><br>Curabitur sodales sem nec nisl finibus, nec suscipit magna euismod.Praesent nibh leo, auctor vel po rttitor in, auctor et sapien.<br> Nullam et nulla rutrum, convallis tellus vitae, eleifend massa
        </p><br>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-half">Get Started</a>

      </li>


      <li class="img2">
        <h2>Slider<span>Slider</span></h2>
        <p>Hello World</p>
        <i class="fab fa-apple"></i>
        <i class="fab fa-android"></i>
        <i class="fab fa-windows"></i>
        <p><br>Curabitur sodales sem nec nisl finibus, nec suscipit magna euismod.Praesent nibh leo, auctor vel po rttitor in, auctor et sapien.<br> Nullam et nulla rutrum, convallis tellus vitae, eleifend massa
        </p><br>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-half">Get Started</a>

      </li>


      <li class="img3">
        <h2>Slider<span>Slider</span></h2>
        <p>Hello World</p>
        <i class="fab fa-apple"></i>
        <i class="fab fa-android"></i>
        <i class="fab fa-windows"></i>
        <p><br>Curabitur sodales sem nec nisl finibus, nec suscipit magna euismod.Praesent nibh leo, auctor vel po rttitor in, auctor et sapien.<br> Nullam et nulla rutrum, convallis tellus vitae, eleifend massa
        </p><br>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-half">Get Started</a>

      </li>

    </ul>

  </section>

  <!-------------Login----------->

  <div class="login-box">
    <div id="login-box">
      <h1>Login</h1>

      <div class="textbox">
        <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="" value="">
      </div>


      <div class="textbox">
        <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Password" name="" value="">
      </div>

      <input class="btn" type="button" name="" value="Sign In">

    </div>
  </div>

  <!-------------FAQ----------->


  <div class="fqcontainer">
    <h1>FAQ Section</h1>
    <div class="acc">
      <h3>Question 1: What is?</h3>
      <div class="fqcontent">
        <div class="content-inner">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In sapien turpis, tincidunt nec maximus et, elementum vel massa. Sed quis suscipit tortor, vel lacinia enim. Pellentesque posuere a urna eget fermentum. Vivamus tincidunt varius turpis,
            eget suscipit arcu aliquam vel. Maecenas fermentum tellus vel euismod porttitor. Curabitur sodales sem nec nisl finibus, nec suscipit magna euismod. Praesent nibh leo, auctor vel porttitor in, auctor et sapien. Nullam et nulla rutrum, convallis
            tellus vitae, eleifend massa</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="acc">
      <h3>Question 1: What is?</h3>
      <div class="fqcontent">
        <div class="content-inner">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In sapien turpis, tincidunt nec maximus et, elementum vel massa. Sed quis suscipit tortor, vel lacinia enim. Pellentesque posuere a urna eget fermentum. Vivamus tincidunt varius turpis,
            eget suscipit arcu aliquam vel. Maecenas fermentum tellus vel euismod porttitor. Curabitur sodales sem nec nisl finibus, nec suscipit magna euismod. Praesent nibh leo, auctor vel porttitor in, auctor et sapien. Nullam et nulla rutrum, convallis
            tellus vitae, eleifend massa</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="acc">
      <h3>Question 1: What is?</h3>
      <div class="fqcontent">
        <div class="content-inner">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In sapien turpis, tincidunt nec maximus et, elementum vel massa. Sed quis suscipit tortor, vel lacinia enim. Pellentesque posuere a urna eget fermentum. Vivamus tincidunt varius turpis,
            eget suscipit arcu aliquam vel. Maecenas fermentum tellus vel euismod porttitor. Curabitur sodales sem nec nisl finibus, nec suscipit magna euismod. Praesent nibh leo, auctor vel porttitor in, auctor et sapien. Nullam et nulla rutrum, convallis
            tellus vitae, eleifend massa</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <!-------------Footer----------->

  <footer>
    <div class="footer">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Log In</a></li>
          <li><a href="">FAQ</a></li>
          <li><a href="">My Surveys</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </footer>


  <script src="main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```